# How can I convert html Element Id to different Id using jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

Here is my html and jquery. I am trying to change object orderForm's billerOrderId to billingAccountNumber. When it is sending to service layer, it is sending as orderForm.billerOrderId instead of sending as orderForm.billingaccountNumber.

```
 <form th:action="@{/orderProcess}" th:object="${orderForm}" method="post">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">

                                        <select class="form-control" id="siteCode" placeholder="select">

                                            <option selected value="1">Billing order number</option>
                                            <option selected value="2">Billing Account Number</option>
                                        </select>


                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-3">

                                        <input type="text"  id="billerOrderId"  name="billerOrderId" formControlName="OrderNumber" maxlength="16"
                                               class="form-control only-numeric" autofocus="autofocus" required />
                                        <span style="display:none;" class=".only-numeric-error">Please enter only numbers</span>

                                    </div>
```

Here is my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            let inp = $('#billerOrderId');
            console.log(inp.attr('id'));
            alert("id = " + inp.attr('id'));
            //$("select.form-control").change(function(){
            var selectedOption = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
            alert("You have selected  - " + selectedOption );

            if (selectedOption == 2 || selectedOption === undefined)  {
                alert("Changing Biller Order Id to Billing Account Number"); 
                inp.attr('id','billingAccountNumber');
                console.log(inp.attr('id'));
                alert("New id = " + inp.attr('id'));
            }
```

I am trying to change object orderForm's billerOrderId to billingAccountNumber.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need jQuery to do this - just plain JS. Simply get the element using document.querySelector()  and then set the attribute using setAttribute('id', ...).

```js
let el = document.querySelector('#billerOrderId');

console.log('Initial ID: ' + el.getAttribute('id'));

el.setAttribute('id', 'billingAccountNumber');

console.log('Changed ID: ' + el.getAttribute('id'));
```

```html
<input type="text"  id="billerOrderId"  name="billerOrderId" formControlName="OrderNumber" maxlength="16" class="form-control only-numeric" autofocus="autofocus" required />
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function textToId(str) {
    var p = str.split(" ");
    p[0] = p[0].toLowerCase();
    return p.join("");
  }

  $("select.form-control").change(function() {
    var inp = $("input[name='billerOrderId']");
    var selectedOption = $(this).val();
    if (selectedOption != "") {
      inp.attr('id', textToId(selectedOption));
      console.log(inp.attr('id'));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form th:action="@{/orderProcess}" th:object="${orderForm}" method="post">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <select class="form-control" id="siteCode" placeholder="select">
      <option></option>
      <option>Billing Order Number</option>
      <option>Billing Account Number</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <input type="text" id="billerOrderId" name="billerOrderId" formControlName="OrderNumber" maxlength="16" class="form-control only-numeric" autofocus="autofocus" required />
    <span style="display:none;" class=".only-numeric-error">Please enter only numbers</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

This adds a function, `textToId()`, that helps format the ID. When the User selects a change in the `select` element, the ID is updated.

Answer (score 0):

***Vanilla JavaScript:***

Comments in code...

```js
// get the select value 
let siteCode = document.getElementById('siteCode');
// get the input value
let textInput = document.getElementById('billerOrderId');
// now add an event listener that listens for blur on the select use this.value and see if it is 
// equal to the value for Billing Account Number, if it is run next line of code
siteCode.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  if (this.value === '2') {
    // event listener on blur to set the value of the inputs id attribute, which is 'Billing Account Number'
    // to this.value, the value of the input
    textInput.addEventListener('blur', function() {
      textInput.id = this.value;
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
I am trying to change object orderForm's billerOrderId to billingAccountNumber. But, i tried using various option but it failed.



<form th:action="@{/orderProcess}" th:object="${orderForm}" method="post">
  <div class="col-md-3">

    <select class="form-control" id="siteCode" placeholder="select">

      <option selected value="1">Billing order number</option>
      <option selected value="2">Billing Account Number</option>
    </select>


  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">

    <input type="text" id="billerOrderId" name="billerOrderId" formControlName="OrderNumber" maxlength="16" class="form-control only-numeric" autofocus="autofocus" required />
    <span style="display:none;" class=".only-numeric-error">Please enter only numbers</span>

  </div>
```

***JQuery:***

```js
//event listener on the select element using blur
$('#siteCode').blur(function() {
  //conditional to see if the select elements value is set to the target value
  if ($(this).val() === '2') {
    //event listener on input using blur
    $('#billerOrderId').blur(function() {
      //set the id attribute of the (billerOrderID) to the value of the input
      $('#billerOrderId').attr('id', $(this).val());
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
I am trying to change object orderForm's billerOrderId to billingAccountNumber. But, i tried using various option but it failed.



<form th:action="@{/orderProcess}" th:object="${orderForm}" method="post">
  <div class="col-md-3">

    <select class="form-control" id="siteCode" placeholder="select">

      <option selected value="1">Billing order number</option>
      <option selected value="2">Billing Account Number</option>
    </select>


  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">

    <input type="text" id="billerOrderId" name="billerOrderId" formControlName="OrderNumber" maxlength="16" class="form-control only-numeric" autofocus="autofocus" required />
    <span style="display:none;" class=".only-numeric-error">Please enter only numbers</span>

  </div>
```

In the below snip I used the string: `Gn5674HGYT` as an example and then opened the console inspection and viewed the elements to get the ID of the input tag. 
***Output from console to show the ID now set to the inputs value:***
[image]